# how do you get the phone's MCC and MNC in Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

The only way I've found of retrieving MCC and MNC is by overriding an activity's onConfigurationChanged method, as such:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    DeviceData.MCC = "" + config.mcc;
    DeviceData.MNC = ""  +config.mnc;
}
```

However,  I need this data as soon as the app starts and can't wait for the user to switch the phone's orientation or equivalent to trigger this method.  Is there a better way to access the current Configuration object?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) has a method to return the MCC+MNC as a String ([getNetworkOperator()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperator())) which will do you what you want. You can get access it via:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String networkOperator = tel.getNetworkOperator();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(networkOperator)) {
        int mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
        int mnc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: `getNetworkOperator()` will return an empty string if a SIM card is not inserted. So the `if` condition should contain `!networkOperator.isEmpty()`. I tested it on my Nexus 5

Comment: Also, it will fail in case of MVNO

Comment: `getNetworkOperator()` returns false. A SIM card is inserted. Why?

Comment: How to handle dual sim devices?

Comment: 'networkOperator.substring(0, 3)' this will get index out of bounds error in some situations

Comment: You can also get the iso country code for MCC by calling `getNetworkCountryIso` instead.

Answer (score 22):

You do know there are two MCC/MNC's for an active phone?  (One is the country code and carrier id for the Sim card, the other is for the network/cell tower in use.)

If the `getResources().getConfiguration().mcc` is not empty in airplane mode, it's the `Sim` value `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()`, not the `tower` value `TelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator()`.

I don't know which the OP wants, but Answer 3 will give him different results than his original code if the `getConfiguration` is really the `Sim` values.

Comment: What is the difference between getNetworkOperator() and getSimOperator();

Answer (score 7):

`getResources().getConfiguration().mcc` is a bad choice because it returns an integer, hence compromising valid values such as `01`, or `044`. Clearly integer is not a good option for this.

See details in [Mobile_Network_Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code)

Update: in Australia, we verified a wrong case here. The `getNetworkOperator` returns different value from `getSimOperator`, where the latter is correct.

See details in Android doc: [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can access the current configuration by `getResources().getConfiguration()` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it turns out that the getResources().getConfiguration().mcc trick is likely better for most purposes, because with the other one if the person puts their phone in airplane mode or otherwise uses Wi-Fi, then it returns an empty MCC.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that network operator sometimes can be like `65@5` when not connected to the operator (service unavailable) even if there is a a SIM card inserted. This happened on Samsung S2 running Android 4.1.2.

[image]

So you have to be careful when converting to Int.

```
 int mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

**this is updated. use this**

```
 TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String networkOperator = tel.getSimOperator();
    System.out.println("************mnc,mcc"+networkOperator);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(networkOperator)) {
         mcc = networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
       mnc = networkOperator.substring(3);System.out.println("************mnc,mcc"+mnc+mcc);
    }mnc_mcc.setText("************mnc,mcc"+mnc+","+mcc);
}
```