# Android MCC / MNC display wrong value

Tags: android

So I was using the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/890945/761670 to check for MCC & MCC in my app.
I got MCC=134 & MNC=38, but this is totally NOT what I was expecting bein in the US with a Cricket Wireless phone...
Looking @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code#U, I expected 310 & 16 - am I doing something wrong or is the Wiki page wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but the answer would have helped me - finally found it.

In the SO question you reference, the code gets the "tower operator" not the SIM operator.

So this line:

```
String networkOperator = tel.getNetworkOperator();
```

Should be this:

```
String networkOperator = tel.getSimOperator();
```

because it's likely Cricket (in your case) isn't the tower operator...