# How to get mobile MNC and MCC code using php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get mobile MCC (Mobile country code) and MNC (Mobile Network code) using php ?

Here it is possible by java that I have seen [how do you get the phone's MCC and MNC in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890366/how-do-you-get-the-phones-mcc-and-mnc-in-android)

If any user access my website using mobile I need to read MNC and MCC code.

I am able to read mobile MSISDN , but In header request I am not seeing any MCC or MNC code.

How it is possible in php ? or is it possible in php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the IMSI, MCC, and MNC for an MSISDN in an HLR. If you don't work for a phone company you have to use a 3rd party API. You'll find them by searching on the internet. For example hlr-lookups.com

Comment: some others are infobip and quadra-mm.com. I worked with both and their api is simple http post using file-get-contents or curl