# Android get MCC + MNC String for neighbouring cells

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, mobile-country-code

> The mobile country code consists of three decimal digits and the mobile network code consists of two or three decimal digits (for example: MNC of 001 is not the same as MNC of 01) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code

so to get MCC + MNC as a string [how do you get the phone's MCC and MNC in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890366/how-do-you-get-the-phones-mcc-and-mnc-in-android) can be used for the main serving cell for an SIM-card slot.

However, instead, I need these values for neighboring cells.

```
telephonyManager::getAllCellInfo
```

returns the list of cells where each nicely holds this information (in theory), but I cannot access it.

My current `minSdkVersion=26.`

```
getAllCellInfo()!!.mapNotNull { cell ->
    when (cell) {
        is CellInfoGsm -> {
            println(cell.cellIdentity.mcc)
            println(cell.cellIdentity.mccString) // only available from 28 onwards
        }
    }
}
...
```

Where:

1. `cell.cellIdentity.mcc` is deprecated
2. `cell.cellIdentity.mcc` returns an int. I.e. I miss any of the leading `0` digits.

How can these be preserved to accurately find the right MCC/MNC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use new `mccString` method only for Android 28 and above. On older API there is no way to get distinct representations for "01" and "001". However these values should be used only for testing purposes and should not be encountered in real life. So, you can just suppress deprecation for `mcc`.

```
telephonyManager.allCellInfo.forEach { cell ->
    if (cell is CellInfoGsm) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            println(cell.cellIdentity.mccString)
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            println(cell.cellIdentity.mcc)
        }
    }
}
```